# CSS selector for targetting the 4th, 5th, 6th, ... of something

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a nested unordered list that is being spat out by a content management system and I need to target a particular set of elements noted below:

```
<ul id="some-list">
    <li>
        <a>[...]</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a>[...]</a>             
            </li>
             <li>
                <a>[...]</a>             
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a>[...]</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a>[...]</a>             
            </li>
             <li>
                <a>[...]</a>             
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>    <li>
        <a>[...]</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a>[...]</a>             
            </li>
             <li>
                <a>[...]</a>             
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>    <li>
        <a>Want this targeted</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a>[...]</a>             
            </li>
             <li>
                <a>[...]</a>             
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>    <li>
        <a>Want this targeted too</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a>[...]</a>             
            </li>
             <li>
                <a>[...]</a>             
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li> 
</ul>
```

To make it more general (in case the client adds extra components), it would be nice to have a selector to target any other `a` tags on the same level, e.g.

```
<ul id="some-list">
    <li>
        <a>[...]</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a>[...]</a>             
            </li>
             <li>
                <a>[...]</a>             
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a>[...]</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a>[...]</a>             
            </li>
             <li>
                <a>[...]</a>             
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>    <li>
        <a>[...]</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a>[...]</a>             
            </li>
             <li>
                <a>[...]</a>             
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>    <li>
        <a>Want this targeted</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a>[...]</a>             
            </li>
             <li>
                <a>[...]</a>             
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>    <li>
        <a>Want this targeted too</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a>[...]</a>             
            </li>
             <li>
                <a>[...]</a>             
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li> 
     <li>
        <a>And this one as well</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a>[...]</a>             
            </li>
             <li>
                <a>[...]</a>             
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li> 
</ul>
```

Only the first, second and third of the `a` tags immediately inside `li`s immediately inside the list are not getting targeted, while the others are.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/awqub7Lr/

Comment: Have you tried [:nth-child()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)?

Comment: If you're able to identify which items you want to pay special attention to, couldn't you add a class to them?

Answer (score 2):

Try this: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/awqub7Lr/3/).

CSS:

```css
#some-list li:nth-child(4) a {
    color: red;
}

#some-list li:nth-child(5) a {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can target all childs after 4th with this css:

```
#some-list li:nth-child(n+4) a {
    color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you looking for this:

```css
ul > li:nth-child(1n+4) > ul > li > a{
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul id="some-list">
    <li> <a>[...]</a>

        <ul>
            <li> <a>[...]</a> 
            </li>
            <li> <a>[...]</a> 
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li> <a>[...]</a>

        <ul>
            <li> <a>[...]</a> 
            </li>
            <li> <a>[...]</a> 
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li> <a>[...]</a>

        <ul>
            <li> <a>[...]</a> 
            </li>
            <li> <a>[...]</a> 
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li> <a>Want this red</a>

        <ul>
            <li> <a>[...]</a> 
            </li>
            <li> <a>[...]</a> 
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li> <a>Want this red too</a>

        <ul>
            <li> <a>[...]</a> 
            </li>
            <li> <a>[...]</a> 
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

or if you want to select and parent `li`:

```css
ul  li:nth-child(1n+4){
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul id="some-list">
    <li> <a>[...]</a>

        <ul>
            <li> <a>[...]</a> 
            </li>
            <li> <a>[...]</a> 
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li> <a>[...]</a>

        <ul>
            <li> <a>[...]</a> 
            </li>
            <li> <a>[...]</a> 
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li> <a>[...]</a>

        <ul>
            <li> <a>[...]</a> 
            </li>
            <li> <a>[...]</a> 
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li> <a>Want this red</a>

        <ul>
            <li> <a>[...]</a> 
            </li>
            <li> <a>[...]</a> 
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li> <a>Want this red too</a>

        <ul>
            <li> <a>[...]</a> 
            </li>
            <li> <a>[...]</a> 
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```